# how to overlay QGraphicsWidgets

Tags: qt

I want to overlay 2 QGraphicsWidgets one on top of the other.
Is there a way to do that?
Ideally I would like to have sth like the QStackedLayout but this is defined only for QWidgets

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsWidget` inherits `QGraphicsItem` too, so you can use default approach to overlay items: change `z-value`.

```
void QGraphicsItem::setZValue ( qreal z )
```

> Sets the Z-value of the item to z. The Z value decides the stacking
>   order of sibling (neighboring) items. A sibling item of high Z value
>   will always be drawn on top of another sibling item with a lower Z
>   value. If you restore the Z value, the item's insertion order will
>   decide its stacking order. The Z-value does not affect the item's size
>   in any way. The default Z-value is 0.